# Facebook Open Graph isn't loading image

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I've put together a micro site that lets users decorate a tree to be shared on facebook/twitter/etc...

http://jajo.net/odditree/share.php?file=u/1418759317.png

Some php magic creates and uploads their image, then sets a variable to be retrieved on the last page.

```
$file = $_GET["file"];
$url = "http://www.jajo.net/odditree/" . $file;
```

Everything is working fine except for the Facebook share dialog.

At first, I tried using a URL to share the image:

```
<a class="btn fb" href="" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=<?echo $url?>&p[images][0]=<?echo $url?>&p[title]=Jajo - Holiday Odditree=', 'newwindow', 'width=600, height=250'); return false;"><span class="icon"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></span> Share on Facebook</a>
```

Sometimes this would load the description, sometimes the image. Never both.

After struggling to make this work I conceded to Facebook's will and created an App.

After following the dev documentation I put this together:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?app_id=823686387676926&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jajo.net%2Fodditree&display=popup&ref=plugin' , 'newwindow', 'width=600, height=250'); return flase;">Facebook Again</a>
```

The site now relies on Facebook for the heavy lifting and all I need to do is provide open graph data.

Here's what that looks like:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Jajo Holiday Odditree">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Jajo Holiday Odditree"> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.jajo.net/odditree/">
<meta property="og:description" content="<?if ($url) {?>Behold my @Jajo Holiday #Odditree! Share your own Odditree creation. http://jajo.net/odditree<?}else{?>Create your own Odditree. http://jajo.net/odditree<?}?>">
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $params['image']; ?>">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="823686387676926">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
```

As far as I can tell, everything is where it needs to be, It even echos the data correctly when I view-source. Yet the share button only shows this:

[image: fb dialog box]

The logo image it's pulling there goes away when it's shared and on my timeline it's just a blank box. Instead of the open graph image:

[image: the source]

I've debugged and scrapped several times, but my og:image always comes up empty.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

I'm at a loss here.

If anyone can help me troubleshoot this issue, I'd really appreciate it.

===UPDATES===
After involving several people, having a lengthy chat, and pulling hair out... We were unable to make this work in time for the site to launch. So we dropped the facebook stuff and it became a twitter campaign.

After all was said and done, my best guess was that it had to do with image sizes.

Comment: I think the problem here was your `og:url` tag on the individual `/share.php?file=xxxx` URLs was pointing to `http://www.jajo.net/odditree/` - this redirects Facebook's crawler to that URL to get the metadata - you should see this in the debug tool output showing which URLs it traversed to get the metadata for the input URL

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues before where no matter what I do it gives options on the image to use with left/right arrows.  Reading a couple things on the web.  One suggests the use of `image_src` tag in the page head.

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://URL-TO-YOUR-IMAGE" / >
```

But that seems like the old way, not the open graph way.  Saw something else that sounds more promising though, clearing FB's cache.

> To force Facebook to refresh it’s cache so that your changes are reflected on Facebook, you must force your page to be “scraped.” The page is scraped when an admin for the page clicks the Like button or when the URL is entered into the Facebook URL Linter.

from this article:
http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/how-to-control-facebook-image-thumbnail-text-popup-dialogs/

Be curious what happens were you to add a second `og:image`.

Comment: I added that in, but it didn't seem to affect the share dialog. As for the scraping, each time I make a change I run it thought the debugger and fetch new info. I'll try adding a second og:image line to see what it does...

Comment: Verify cache is in fact cleared...?  Append something to description perhaps?

Comment: Adding a second line did something unexpected... With that in place it started having the early issue where it either showed an image or description, but not both... very perplexing.

Comment: In response to your earlier comment, yes. Cache is definitely being cleared.

Comment: Sorry, beats me.  Your mark up looks good but maybe pastebin it, can check more closely for errors.  Maybe escaping/echoing poorly in PHP, invalid and defaults to what you are getting?

Comment: Here's a pastebin of the share page, with header and footer included: http://pastebin.com/x4ejsgL8 Thanks for taking the time to help me out today...

Comment: Can't remember how to start a chat on here... anyway, we seeing the same thing? http://imagebin.ca/v/1ksSngKv1xhF  Actually posted to my feed and looks like I assume you would want it to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67060/discussion-between-mdcrtv-and-ficuscr).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you didn't make it in time.

I just had my own frustrating time, and my solution could have been yours.  I'll post it here for any who follow along behind us.  Facebook OG:Image not displaying.  Agh!!! I can't believe how much time I wasted last night and today on this.  It was maddening!  I followed every rabbit trail, and Facebook continued to ignore my og:image property (I even removed the url redirect for ssl in my web.config and re-coded the site so that I could have an unsecure and a secure version of the image). Everything looked right to me, but it kept ignoring the property.

Then...

I went here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=POST&path=%3Fscrape%3Dtrue%26id%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&version=v5.0

This is the tool you want to use, not this one:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com

The explorer gives you detailed error messages that the sharing debug tool does not, in my case specifically:

I had spaces in my image filename that weren't url encoded.  Have a space in your filename and it will browse just fine, but it will be rejected by Facebook for the property on the sharing debugger page without any error message (not sure why they call it a debugger, the explorer is the real debugger).  (If I can save even just one person from this, then my misery was worth it).

Oh ya... the link for the explorer is at the very bottom of the "debugger" page (titled Scrape Via API).